# Получить объект из БД

Tags: java, android, sqlite

Есть объект ObjectA в нем есть поле ObjectB и соответственно есть две таблицы A и B. Как мне правильно получать объект ObjectB. Сразу скажу что не хочу пользоваться OrmLite, Realm и т.д. Только SQLite только хардкор. Так хочу узнать быть может есть какое-то правильное и красивое решение данной задачи?

```
public class ObjectA {

  private int id;
  private ObjectB objB;

  ObjectA(Cursor cursor) {
    id = CursorUtils.getInt("id", cursor);
    objB = ?
    по идее тут должен получить ID ObjectB который будет соотв. записи в таблице B. После чего получить запись и создать из неё объект.
  }

}

public class ObjectB {

  private int id;
  private String descr;

}
```

База выглядит следующим образом.
Таблица A:
id integer
objB integer

Таблица B:
id integer
decr text

Comment: Покажите SQL запрос которым вы пытались решить эту задачу.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Для решения вашего вопроса (получить объект из SQLite)  лучше всего подходит решение, озвученное в книге Б.Харди "Android. Программирование для профессионалов"-2015 на 290 странице - глава "Использование CursorWrapper"

Смысл в том, что враппер создает "прослойку" между курсором и запрашивающим данные классом, что позволяет с одной стороны использовать "нативные" инструменты работы с SQLite, а с другой стороны получать в качестве результата запроса не сырую выборку курсора, а объект.

Примерно все это выглядит так.

Сам класс-враппер:

```
public class SomeCursorWrapper extends CursorWrapper {
    public SomeCursorWrapper(Cursor cursor) {
        super(cursor);
    }

    public ObectA getObject() {
        String title = getString(getColumnIndex(Database.TITLE));
        long date = getLong(getColumnIndex(Database.DATE));

        ObjectA obj = new ObectA();
        obj.setTitle(title);
        obj.setDate(new Date(date));
        return obj;
    }
}
```

использование, к примеру получить объект из курсора по ID:

```
public ObjectA getObectA(long id) {

    Cursor с = Database.query(
            "someTable",
            null, 
            "_id = ?",
            new String[]{Long.toString(id)},
            null, 
            null, 
            null 
    );
    SomeCursorWrapper cursor = new SomeCursorWrapper (c);
    cursor.moveToFirst();
    return cursor.getObect();
}
```

Естественно, что не обязательно получать курсор прямо в методе, враппер может использовать полученный ранее курсор. Смысл класса в том, что ему отдаешь курсор, а получаешь в ответ объект.

Поскольку вменяемых аналогов в интернете мне найти не удалось и если вас заинтересовало данное решение, вам нужно будет найти эту книгу для получения подробностей.

Посмотреть все это в деле вы можете в [этом проекте](https://github.com/amogh147/CriminalIntent) - классы `CrimeCursorWrapper` и `CrimeLab`

Насчет получения объекта, как одного из полей таблицы, с учетом того, что в поле ObjB хранится ID на соответствующую строку в таблице B, то что то вроде такого запроса должно решить проблему.

Запрос для rawQuery, такой вариант предпочтительней:

```
SELECT * FROM A LEFT JOIN B ON A.ObjB = B.id
```

Запрос для query (с преобразованием для непосредственно метода проблем возникнуть не должно):

```
SELECT * FROM A,B WHERE A.ObjB = B.id
```

В результате этой выборки мы получим записи в курсор, каждая строка которой будет содержать столбцы таблицы A и столбцы из таблицы B с ID совпадающим с числом, хранящимся в поле ObjB таблицы A. Для уменьшения проблем в одной из таблиц поле *id* нужно переименовать во что то другое, вроде *id_B*. То есть каждая строка, полученная таким запросом будет иметь следующую структуру столбцов (с учетом предложенного переименования):

```
| id | ObjB | id_B | decr |
```

Если какие то столбцы не требуются их можно исключить, указав в запросе вместо "*" имена столбцов обоих таблиц, которые должны попасть в выборку (например исключить ObjB, так как он не несет более полезной информации:

```
SELECT A.id, B.id_B, B.decr FROM A LEFT JOIN B ON A.ObjB = B.id
```

Если требуется не все записи, а только одна с определенным ID из таблицы A (здесь с ID = 1, на место цифры можно поставить любое значение через переменную в коде):

```
SELECT A.id, B.id_B, B.decr FROM A,B WHERE A.id = 1 AND A.ObjB = B.id
```

В враппере остается только извлечь эти данные и раскидать по соответствующим объектам. Поскольку конкретного кода по работе с БД вы не приложили, я не буду писать абстрактный пример, думаю вы, как ценитель хардкора, сами в силах применить эту информацию :)

Answer (score 0):

> Для уменьшения проблем в одной из таблиц поле id нужно переименовать во что то другое, вроде id_B
> ...
>
> `SELECT A.id, B.id_B, B.decr FROM A LEFT JOIN B ON A.ObjB = B.id`

Вы издеваетесь? Зачем переименовывать колонки в базе? Про алиас поля выборки на слыхали?

```
SELECT A.id, B.id as id_B, B.decr as descr_B
FROM A LEFT JOIN
     B ON (A.ObjB = B.id);
```

Ради одного запроса нет нужды (да и глупо) переименовывать поля в БД. Тем более есть стандартное простое решение. А вообще, рекомендую топик-стартеру книгу Мартина Грубера "Понимание SQL", она маленькая, но даёт знания, которые сильно упрощают жизнь.