# Как использовать объект для двух смежных экранов?

Tags: java, android, ооп

Есть, например, `Экран 1` со списком самолетов (Отображаем название и цвет), мне достаточно такого объекта:

```
class Aircraft {
    private String name;
    private int color; 
}
```

Когда я нажимаю на один из самолетов из списка, переходим к `Экрану 2`, где отображаем дополнительно подробные характеристики выбранного самолета (Мощность двигателя, грузоподъемность и, предположим, ещё 20 полей), соответственно, класса `Aircraft`мне недостаточно.  Данные берем, например, из локальной базы данных, и, я думаю, лучше для каждого экрана отдельно. Как лучше сделать, создать отдельно класс, например `AircraftExtendet`, для `Экрана 2` или расширить первый класс?

Comment: Данные о самолетах где хранятся у вас?

Comment: @Victor база данных

Comment: Локальная или же на сервере?

Comment: @Victor локальная

Comment: для первой активити даже класса не нужно. можете сохранить в мапу или еще куда то список имен и цветов. Для второй активити создайте полноценный класс. Если же в первой активити параметров поболее, можете создать класс, допустим `BaseAircraft` и во второй унаследоваться от базового класса

Comment: @Victor великолепная идея!

Comment: Если у вас БД - берите банные прямо из БД и работайте с курсором. Вам не нужны эти обертки-модели. Если сильное желание к моделям, используйте ООБД, как Realm.

Comment: какая?) с классом или без?)

Comment: @Victor c классом

Comment: @pavlofff Спасибо. Так же очень хороший вариант.

Comment: @pavlofff Просто я делаю приложение с использование MVP, объекты думаю лучше подойдут.

Comment: Посмотрите [это решение](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/535778/177345) тогда, а лучше примотреться [к Realm](https://realm.io/docs/java/latest/)/ Насчет классов - вам не нужно делать несколько классов-моделей, один из которых содежит поля другого. Используйте один класс-модель с максимальным набором полей, где требуется меньшее количество данных просто получайте нужные из всего набора, это будет эффективнее.

Comment: @pavlofff CursorWrapper-a пока не увидел преимуществ, нужно ещё почитать. Realm использовать не получится, так как с сервера качается база sqlite и переделывать её никто не хочет.

Comment: @pavlofff разве что другую ORM подобрать использующую sqlite

Comment: @pavlofff А по поводу одного класса, мне кажется, что решение с использованием двух классов более красивое, и в чем оно проигрывает я не вижу. Для первого экран данные будут быстрее грузится и будут меньше занимать места в памяти с использование двух объектов

Comment: Да, я сейчас подумал, "тащить" лишнюю инфу не очень удачная идея. С другой стороны вам не нужно наследование. Оно применяется для другого, например: Самолет -> Boeing, у вас же равнозначные сущности. Просто сделайте два класса: `Aircraft` и `AircraftFull`, например. Вы же их будете заполнять через разные выборки из БД в курсоры. Так же в первом случае вам нужна выборка по множеству записей для списка, во втором только по одному конкретному самолету - это два разных метода. Наследование никак не улучшит.

Comment: @pavlofff остановился на мнении, что классы в данном случае можно наследовать, так как согласно вики: "Концептуально, полиморфизм подтипов устанавливает отношение: «является» (англ. is-a relationship), — тем самым имитируя семантическое отношение наследования;" AircraftExtendet "является" Aircraft. + в примерах так же используют подобное наследование.